# Check internet connection with InternetGetConnectedState always true

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I need to check in my Compact Framework app if it has internet connection.

So looking around I found the `InternetGetConnectedState` method, but in my case every time I check if I have internet connection it returns true, even when I am offline.

Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(ref InternetConnectionState_e lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

[Flags]enum InternetConnectionState_e : int
{
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = 0x01,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = 0x02,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = 0x04,
    INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED = 0x10,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE = 0x20,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = 0x40
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    verify();
}

private void verify()
{
    // In function for checking internet
    InternetConnectionState_e flags = 0;
    bool isConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(ref flags, 0);
    textBox1.Text = "Con: " + isConnected.ToString();
    textBox1.Text += "\r\nDescr: " + flags.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    verify();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say you are 'offline' do you mean that your local system is explicitly in the offline state? That's what this call means by offline. To my knowledge, the only reliable way to detect if you can access the internet is to try it and see if it fails.

Comment: Yep. What are you trying to connect to? Can you connect to it? If not, then assume you're not connected.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to find a way of know if I a mobile is connected to Internet. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your [P/Invoke internetgetconnectedstate](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/internetgetconnectedstate.html) signature might be a little off.

Copying from the link above, the signature appears to look for an `int` as the first parameter:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError=true)]
extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int lpdwFlags Description, int dwReserved );

[Flags]
enum ConnectionStates
{
    Modem = 0x1,
    LAN = 0x2,
    Proxy = 0x4,
    RasInstalled = 0x10,
    Offline = 0x20,
    Configured = 0x40,
}
```

The example code usage appears simple enough:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  internal class Program
  {
   [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    int flags;
    bool isConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(out flags, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Is connected :{0} Flags:{1}", isConnected, flags));
   }
  }
}
```

What errors are you getting? You could always wrap the `InternetGetConnectedState` method in a `try...catch` block:

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    int flags;
    bool isConnected = false;
    try
    {
      isConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(out flags, 0);
    } catch (Exception err)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Is connected :{0} Flags:{1}", isConnected, flags));
   }
  }
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE** Based on your `flags = 18` results:

`flags` is defined as an `int`, so 18 is a Decimal representation.

In Binary, this would be `0001 0010`, which would map to `LAN (0x2) | RasInstalled (0x10)`.

So, I'm guessing you are connected via a Local Area Network, but it does not guarantee the LAN has Internet Access. To test that, you would need to try to browse to a known good site.

**RAS** I am not sure about. [Remote Access Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS)?

Keep in mind: A device cradled/docked in the charger could register as `Connected`, too.

Comment: I make that try and it gives the same result when I am online and offline: *isConnected = true* and *Flags = 18*

Comment: `flags=18` looks like you are connected. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok, but in my case it always give me *18* as result. I make the tests browsing to google each time and when I am connected and when I'm not it gives the same result (always outside the docked).

Comment: All of our devices here at work can connect to our LAN, but they are not connected to the Internet. Not sure, but I think this is done on our end by our Network Administrator via the Group Policy settings.